# Kooha and built-in screen recorder do not record the mouse pointer

Tags: desktop-recording

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04.1 LTS and used various screen recorders to record screen regions (I don't care about audio). In Ubuntu 18 I used Peek, but the project has been deprecated and it didn't work when I upgraded so I tried Kooha and OBS as suggested in many discussions. The problem with Kooha and the build-in Ubuntu screen recorder (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R) is that they don't seem to record the mouse pointer, no matter what settings I choose. Please bear in mind that I have a custom mouse cursor (McMojave-cursors). OBS records everything fine, including the mouse pointer, but it is very cumbersome to use because it's not easy to select the precise region you want to capture (it only supports a crop section that you need to manually enter with numbers).
Any ideas?

Comment: If Kooha doesn't record your cursor even you configure to do so, maybe you should [file a bug](https://github.com/SeaDve/Kooha/issues)

Comment: @guiverc sorry, I didn't know there was a difference between 22 and 22.04. Indeed, I'm using 22.04.

Comment: @guiverc done. I hope it's clear now.